# Running executable from an HTTP header

Tags: html, http, executable

I am currently building an application which the requires the user to login on a web page first, and from this web page he or she can run the application. The website is hosted on a server, and eventually I need to launch the application on the client.

The website is built using .NET . Is it possible to send some http request or html url which opens an already installed program?

Thanks.

Comment: So the application is installed on client side already? What browsers are going to be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by registering a URI scheme on the machine associated with your program, and having the browser navigate to a URI of that scheme.

Steam for example does this - there is a steam:// URI scheme registered by the steam installer and associated with the desktop application. When a browser or another application browses to steam://something then that is passed as an argument to Steam to act on it.

This method requires no special privileges, and the user is prompted for permission to start the application.

Comment: I came across the following code segment earlier today :

<script>
            function LaunchApp() {
                if (!document.all) {
                    alert("Available only with Internet Explorer.");
                    return;
                }
                var ws = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
                ws.Exec("C:\\Windows\\notepad.exe");
            }
        </script>

Is there some similar workaround? Unluckily this launches the app on the server rather than on the client.

Thanks for the response guys.

Comment: That launches stuff on the client, but it's specific to internet explorer and probably doesn't work unless the side is in a trusted zone. You should look into how to configure a URI scheme so you can do it properly.

Comment: Big thanks mate :) I'll start looking for some tutorials then. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered [ClickOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/t71a733d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for deploying the application? This can act as your launcher, deployer and will ensure the application is up to date.